# "Steam failed to load: *SteamStartEngine(0xbfffdf54) failed with error 1: A Steam Engine Instance already exists"

Tags: steam

My Mac Steam installation on 10.7 has started giving this "failed to load" dialog whenever I try to launch Steam.

I have tried deleting the Application Support folder which allowed Steam to launch but then I had to redownload the games *again*, and I have a feeling that it is handling the symptom, not the cause.

What is the reason (what does Steam check for, so I can look) and how do I fix it?

Comment: Interesting, it seems to be trying to load a shared object but thinks one is already loaded.  +1ing this, i'd love to see the answer.

Comment: This time a reboot allowed it to start.  It did not the last time.

Comment: @Robb, how did you determine that this was happening?

Comment: OH, I'm not certain, simply a guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is caused by a component of Steam not stopping correctly, and then when you try and reopen Steam it complains.

Open a terminal window and run the following command (type it in and press enter):

```
    ps -A | grep Steam
```

This will give you a list of running programs that have the word 'Steam' in them - usually 2 or 3. When I had your error and ran the above command this is what I saw:

```
    712 ??       700:23.42 /Applications/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/osx32/steam -psn_0_40970
    64849 ttys002    0:00.00 grep Steam
```

One of the items will be called 'grep Steam' - ignore that one. Each item in the list will have a number - this is the first piece of text on each line. The number we are interested in here is 712.

Run the following command to close the lingering Steam component:

```
    kill 712
```

Where you replace 712 with whatever number you found. If there was more than 1 number, run kill again with the other numbers too.

You should now be able to close the terminal, and run Steam just like normal. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work :(  I killed three processes, ran the ps command again to make sure they were gone (they were), opened steam and got the same error.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Found something that sounds promising [in a thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=15089249&postcount=12) posted to steam official forum:

> > Please exit Steam and go to the folder Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Steam
> >
> > Delete all of the files in this folder.
> >
> > Then, you will need to launch Steam.app from your Dock or Applications folder.
> >
> > With Steam running, re-test the original issue.
> >
> > Note: This process will not affect your currently installed games.

Comment: Thats what I did that required re-download :(

Comment: So you still get the same error even after doing this?

Comment: It took care of the problem, but required me to redownload the games.  After a few days the problem came back and prompted me to open the question.

Comment: I see.. sorry for that. Do you happen to have multiple user accounts on your Mac machine? E.g. one for you and one for other family member(s)?

Comment: Yes, but it is not used.  I am the only user of the machine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mac, but there is chance that Steam is running for each account hence giving you such error.

Comment: Note: I have not seen this for quite a while now.

Comment: Cheers, there were quite a few Steam client updates since so maybe one of them solved this issue. :)

Comment: This has just started happening to me in the last couple of days - Steam randomly crashes then I get this error.  Hopefully they'll fix it again, as I haven't found a solution other than rebooting the computer (I don't want to delete all my games).